# can't install any package in atom

Tags: atom-editor

[image: error pic1]

[image: error pic2]

I can't install any package in my atom. it displays one "show output" message, when I click on this, it shows the following error message.

> Error Message  "Fetching featured packages failed.Hide output… write EPROTO 101057795:error:140943F2:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert unexpected message:openssl\ssl\s3_pkt.c:1493:SSL alert number 10 101057795:error:1409E0E5:SSL routines:ssl3_write_bytes:ssl handshake failure:openssl\ssl\s3_pkt.c:659:"

Comment: I have not used atom yet.. but might be you are not installing secured package

Comment: Do packages appear if you clear the search field? If they don't it could be a kind of network problem on your end, try browsing https://packages.atom.io

Comment: Packages don't appear in search bar. What kind of network problem it can be?

Comment: It's an SSL error, which means that some entity in the chain of computers from where the data is stored on GitHub to your machine is not sufficiently secure. Do you have the ability to download packages from a different network?

Comment: Yes, I tried from my wifi as well from my mobile wifi too. But still disappointed.

Answer (score 2):

Finally, I got a solution to this problem after stuck for long time. Actually I was before I was installing 64-bit of Atom setup, but now installed 32-bit setup of atom.

Answer (score -1):

turn off windows defender and firewall then you can install packages after these works you can turn on firewall

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).